# Display images on site from folder outside public_html folder

Tags: php, linux

I am using codeingiter and had a image directory in it. Due to space issue I have shifted the entire directory to new location on same server.

Earlier path was /var/www/html/site_folder/assets/images

New Location is /home/new_site/images

Now when I want to display images on web site its not getting load.

I have tried using the below code

> $file = '/home/new_site/images/3.jpg';
>
> header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
>
> echo "<img src='".readfile($file)."' &glt;";

I have approximately 50 images and I want to load them on my site.

This works on local but not on server. I am using **Linux** on local and **Centos** on server.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things up. What you want to do is to return the content of the image file, but you return an HTML fragment.

There are multiple solutions you could try:

1. Create a symbolic link to the new image directory, most things could stay as they are. This migth or might not work depending on your web server configuration.
2. Change all the references to images from

   `src="image5.jpg"`

   to something

   `src="image.php?name=image5.jpg"`

Then you need the script "image.php" which takes the name of the image as a query parameter and then returns the content:

```
<?php
    // take care to make some clever checks here
    // otherwise you introduce a security nightmare
    $file = '/home/new_site/images/'  . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, you mean to say that i will have to create a file image.php and put below code in it $file = '/home/new_site/images/'  . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    readfile($file);

Comment: Yes, you have to pass the raw image data to the browser. The script is untested, but it should give you a picture how it can be done.

Comment: So if there are 100 images then I will have to write a foreach..?

Comment: Maybe you didn't describe your problem properly. The code is supposed to help you with references to images in your HTML code. Your images moved, means you have to change the "src" attribute for the moved images. If you moved the images out of the directory, the web server has direct access to, you need some kind of magic/proxy to get the data for these files. This is what the PHP script is supposed to do.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above solution on my local and it worked but when  I promoted the same code to the server its showing broken image. Image is present in that directory.

Comment: This could be anything from encoding to server configuration. If the solution works please accept the answer.

Comment: I am using nginx to serve static contents like images, css and js... Is nginx causing the problem??